# How can i sort my Arraylist?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have this user class

```
public class User {

public String userName;
public int highScore = 0;

public static ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>(5);

public User(String name, int score) {
    this.userName = name;
    this.highScore = score;
    userList.add(this);

    Collections.sort(userList, new Comparator<User>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(User lhs, User rhs) {
            return lhs.highScore-rhs.highScore;
        }

    });

}
```

}

The User object has properties name and score.i want to sort my list on the basis of score of the user.

Comment: Please tag your questions with the appropriate language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    java.util.Collections.sort(userList, new Comparator<User>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(User lhs, User rhs) {
            return lhs.getScore() - rhs.getScore();
        }

    });
```

Comment: @user2015770 what is not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Create an object that implements Comparator:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

This essentially implements a comparison between two objects. From this, you can use automatic sort methods.

```
public class UserComparator implements Comparator {
    public boolean compare(Object object1, Object object2) {
        return ... \\ result of comparison
    }
}
public static ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>(5);

Collections.sort(usersList, new UserComparator());
```

the return value is an int.

```
0 if object1 equals object2
a negative int if object1 < object2
a positive int if object1 > object2
```

Comment: what should be the result?

Comment: The result is 0 if object1 equals object2, a negative int if object1 is less than object2, a positive int if object1 is more than object2.

Comment: not working.tried returning lhs.highScore-rhs.highScore

Comment: Give more details. Will it not compile? Does it fail at run time? Or does it simply not sort them?

Comment: it is compiling but not sorting.

Comment: Is it: not changing values at all; or changing them, but not as expected?